# Is there a way by which I can append time stamp to the generated reports in Newman?

Tags: postman, newman

Is there a way by which I can append time stamp to the generated reports in Newman? As of now, every time we need to change the report name to generate unique reports.

Answer (score 0):

When I run newman and tell it to generate an html report:

```
newman run "Login test.postman_test_run.json" --reporters html
```

I ran it twice and it generated two files called:

```
newman-run-report-2017-05-19-18-48-23-021-0.html
newman-run-report-2017-05-19-18-50-43-702-0.html
```

Maybe you have an old version of Newman (I'm using newman@3.6.0).

If it is old version, update it with

```
npm install newman --global
```

Comment: Thanks for your respnse. I was using a different command "set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy & newman run collec.json -e environmentVariable.json --reporters cli,html --reporter-html-export report1.html" by which it just generated the report by the name specified.